# Okhttp infinite loop on change connection status

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, okhttp

I have simple code for making request with okHttp lib:

```
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
    Log.d("TAG", "start");
    Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    Log.d("TAG", "stop");
```

Everything works well, unless I try to change connection, while execute request. Ex, if I try to connect without wifi (with slow internet connection), and turn on wifi while it's in progress it will execute infinitely. But if I stay with slow mobile internet or stay with wifi (without changing connection type) all works fine. Same story when I turn off all connections, start execution and then turn on connection. 
I tried to use timeout, but it doesn't help.

**Edit.** There is no other valuable code:

```
private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private AsyncCallback<Reader> callback;

    private DownloadXmlTask(AsyncCallback<Reader> callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            Reader result = doGetRequest(urls[0]);
            callback.success(result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.debug(context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_http_request), e);
            callback.failure(context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_http_request), e);
        }
        return null;
    }

}

private Reader doGetRequest(String url) throws IOException {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        Log.d("MYTAG", "start");
        Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
        Log.d("MYTAG", "stop");
        return response.body().charStream();
    }
```

OkHttp version:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
```

Comment: What's the code surrounding this block?

Comment: Can you provide an executable test case?

Comment: I'm currently experiencing this, it happens every time I go from slow connection to wifi. My workaround plan is to detect connection change with a broadcast receiver and if there's a call currently happening, to interrupt it and try again.

Comment: did you find a fix for this problem ?